# Android instrumented test coverage report on Jenkins - Incompatible JaCoCo version

Tags: android, jenkins, jacoco

I've got a problem when I launch a build on Jenkins. I would like to have the coverage report of my instrumented tests in Jenkins but it fails due to an incompatible version of Jacoco.

In my Android project, I've added the line **apply plugin: 'jacoco'** in the *app/build.gradle* file.
My Android project use the gradle plugin 3.0.1 version.

In Jenkins, I set up my application like this:
[image]
[image]

In Jenkins, I've installed the JaCoCo plugin 3.0.1 version.

When I run a build in Jenkins with this configuration, it goes well but I don't get the coverage report of the instrumented tests.

So, I change the settings like this:
[image]

When I run a build, in the *Console output*, I get the following message:

> ERROR: Step ‘Record JaCoCo coverage report’ aborted due to exception: 
>   org.jacoco.core.data.IncompatibleExecDataVersionException: Cannot read execution data version 0x1006. This version of JaCoCo uses execution data version 0x1007.

On the Jenkins wiki, I read that there is a compatibility problem between different versions of Jenkins and JaCoCo: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JaCoCo+Plugin.
So, I tried to use a 7.5+ version in my Android project by adding this line in the build.gradle file:

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion '0.7.5+'
}
```

But it still fails... :-(

I don't understand why it works with the *.exec files only but not when I add the *.ec files.

Someone see what I missed?